# Error when tapping on anything inside loaded page in WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an issue with WKWebview. The pages load without any problems, but whenever I tap on any button on website, slide photos or accept cookies policy I get the following error:

> 2019-10-14 11:27:02.933458+0200 AppTitle[2592:447958] [general] Connection to daemon was invalidated

Does anyone know what may be the issue or what am I missing? This error causes further problems inside the app. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import TinyConstraints

class DetailsVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

let myUrl = URL(string: "https://google.pl/")

var webView: WKWebView = {

    let webview = WKWebView()
    return webview

}()

func addWebView() {

  view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.edgesToSuperview(insets: .top(40) + .right(0) + .left(0), usingSafeArea: true)
    webView.navigationDelegate  = self
    webView.uiDelegate          = self
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: self.myUrl!))

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add webview
    addWebView()

    }

}
```

Comment: @Tmothy Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue